# Method of Moments for $\nu$ of standard t-distribution: what if true $\nu=2$?

Tags: distributions, t-distribution, method-of-moments

Note I am considering the standard $t$ distribution $(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$

The method of moments for $\nu>2$ is derived [in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/186607/106860)

My question is, if the true (population) value of $\nu$ is $2$, **and we don't know this**, then what is the MOM estimator estimating?

My confusion is that in this case the MOM estimator uses higher order moments that don't exist, so does this mean that if $\nu=2$ the MOM estimator will never get this right?

More generally, if we use a MOM estimator based on moments that only exist for certain parameter values, what happens if the true parameter values are not in that range?

Comment: Even when $\nu=3$ or $4$, say, the MOM estimator may be quite poor at typical sample sizes. Just because a MOM exists  doesn't mean it will necessarily be much use. Note that if the mean and variance are unknown, the estimation of $\mu,\sigma^2$ and $\nu$ could mean [using up to 4th moments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52989/t-distribution-method-of-moments) ... whose variance relies on *8th* moments. If you have $\nu\leq 8$ your estimator for $\nu$ doesn't have finite variance.

Comment: @Glen_b I see. What I am asking though is whether the MOM estimator will be able to (correctly) predict that $\nu=2$ (if that is the true value), **asymptotically** (i.e. if we have an infinitely large sample size).

If the true $\nu>2$, then I believe the MOM is consistent for $\nu$, but we derived the MOM estimator assuming $\nu>2$, so if the true value of $\nu=2$, I'm not sure whether the consistency of the MOM estimator means anything, since we derived it using a moment that doesn't exist in the population then?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to converge *to* (in that the function of moments has an undefined expectation). Horst already answered that in the first sentence of his answer. I was giving information to indicate it might not be of much practical use even when it converges to the population value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, the estimators are no more consistent. The consistency of a working MOM estimator is guaranteed by the consistency of the moment estimators plus the fact that the parameter is a continuous function of the moments.